# How To Display Posts Of Custom Post Type At Page Template

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

Suppose Your post type slug is cars :

Code For Display Posts At Page Template:

```
<?php /* Template Name: cars  */ 
get_header();

$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'cars',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'ASC'
);?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
<?php   

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>

    <tr>
         /*for display post Title*/
        <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
        /*for display posts Thumbnail*/
        <td><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php endwhile;endif;?>

</table>

<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Note: pastle this to new created file in active themes folder save it and select template after created page in back end of WordPress
I Hope this will Help :)

Comment: WordPress Stack Exchange! Please explain what your question is.

Comment: This is a question for me before 3 month and i search whole internet but i didn't found that's why i think today when i know the answer i should post that's why i posted.

Comment: Then post question and answer as separate posts. This way you might even get a better answer, which filtering `pre_get_posts`, not a new query. :)